# Comparing 2 arrays, 1 an answer key, one a string

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im working on a tic-tac-toe game, and I'm trying to compare 2 arrays.
One array has the winning answer combinations:

```
var answers = ["1,2,3", "1,4,7", "2,5,8", "3,6,9", "4,5,6", "7,8,9", "1,5,9", "3,5,7"];
```

Depending on the div clicked, an array is is filled with that divs correlating value. So, if 'X' clicks the 1st, 3rd & 5th divs, the array for player X = `1,3,5`.

If player X then clicks box 2, he wins, because he'll have 3 in a row, because when `1,3,5,2` is compared to the `answers` array, `answers[0]` contains all of those values too.

I was trying to compare strings first, but the order is an issue, so went with trying to compare integers. Still not sure if that's right or not.

Comment: why not use use an array inside instead of strings?

Comment: My fault. It was an error when I initially filled in the array. Ok, Im not opposed to that. I have 3mos of coding experience, so not sure of your reasoning, or how to do that. So you're saying put an array inside my array?

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate the `answers` and check then the winnig positions against the selected positions.

This proposal uses

- [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for iterating `answers`.

  > The **`some()`** method tests whether some element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.
- [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), to get the winning positions inside of the string.

  > The **`split()`** method splits a String object into an array of strings by separating the string into substrings.
- [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for checking all positions

  > The **`every()`** method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function.
- [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) for testing an array against an item. The item is converted to Number.

  > The **`indexOf()`** method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

```js
function check(pos) {
    var answers = ["1,2,3", "1,4,7", "2,5,8", "3,6,9", "4,5,6", "7,8,9", "1,5,9", "3,5,7"];
    return answers.some(function (a) {
        return a.split(',').every(function (b) {
            return pos.indexOf(+b) !== -1;
        });
    });
}

console.log(check([1, 3, 5]));    // false
console.log(check([1, 3, 5, 2])); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time a player takes a turn, you'll want to validate whether they won during that turn. That means that your data structure should support easy validation of a win, without too much pre-processing. There are a few reasons why strings are a bad fit for this. Firstly, if you're using direct string comparison, you can't correctly match completed games like `1,2,3,5`, because there were turns that didn't contribute to the game being completed.

This means you'll want to consider each box individually, by splitting the string into an array, and iterating over its values. However this still isn't ideal, since you have to split the string after each player's turn, even though the resulting array will always be the same. So you might as well just store the answers as an array of arrays.

Then, once you have that array of arrays, you just need to verify that there is [*some*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) answer (i.e. at least one) in that array where [*every*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) one of the boxes is [*included*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) in the player's guesses.

This results in a fairly terse expression:

```
var answers = [
  [1,2,3], [1,4,7], [2,5,8], 
  [3,6,9], [4,5,6], [7,8,9],
  [1,5,9], [3,5,7]
];

function isWinningGuess(guesses) {
  return answers.some(answer => answer.every(box => guesses.includes(box)));
}
```

Here, `guesses` is an array containing each box that the player has selected.

For a complete working example, see the code snippet below, and run the demo application.

```js
var answers = [
  [1,2,3], [1,4,7], [2,5,8], 
  [3,6,9], [4,5,6], [7,8,9],
  [1,5,9], [3,5,7]
];

function isWinningGuess(guesses) {
  return answers.some(answer => answer.every(x => guesses.includes(x)));
}

// Below code for visualization only
$(function() {
  var current = 0;
  var players = [
    { 'symbol': 'X', 'plays': [] },
    { 'symbol' : 'O', 'plays' : [] }
  ];

  $(".row > div").click(function() {
    if ($(this).text() != '-') return;
    var player = players[current];

    $(this).html("<span>" + player.symbol + "</span>");

    var row = $(this).closest('.row').index();
    var col = $(this).index();
    var boxNumber = row * 3 + col + 1;
    player.plays.push(boxNumber);

    $("#status").text("Last Move: " + player.symbol + ' chose ' + boxNumber);

    if (isWinningGuess(player.plays)) {
      $("#status").append('; ' + player.symbol + ' wins!');
      $(".row > div").off('click');
    }
    
    current ^= 1;
  });
});
```

```css
.row {
  height: 45px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.row > div {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: pink;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="result"></div>
<div id="status">Last Move: </div>

<div>
<div class="row">
  <div>-</div> <div>-</div> <div>-</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div>-</div> <div>-</div> <div>-</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div>-</div> <div>-</div> <div>-</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this very detailed feedback @nbrooks! I am rereading to understand & trying 2 replicate so I can understand it. Thanks again!!